# Account to install Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I installed SharePoint with my student account on campus, which has only read permission. Here are some problems.

1. What kind of permission do I need to install and configure Sharepoint, for now I use my student account that given full control of the server computer that I work on. But it seems like I could not do anything in Active Directory(Add role, modify role etc.)
2. Will it work if I use the same account for both SQL and SharePoint since it's the only account that I have.
3. When I install workflow manager, I tried to use my account as run as account it showed it was invalid. But it worked if I use a local account that I created it on the machine. But have problem when I put commend on PowerShell:

[image]

This is the command that I entered. But when I opened the site it gave me error like follow:

`AuthorizationError`The caller does not have the necessary permissions required for this operation. Permissions granted: None. Required permissions: ReadScope.

Comment: did you install the SharePoint in you'r local machine as a single farm?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Install account require:

1. It must have domain user account permissions.
2. It must be a member of the local administrators group on each server in the SharePoint farm.
3. This account must have access to the SharePoint databases.
4. If you use any Windows PowerShell operations that affect a database, the setup user administrator account must be a member of the `db_owner` role.
5. This account must be assigned to the `securityadmin` and `dbcreator` SQL Server security roles during setup and configuration.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662513.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have the problem with your account as long as it fullfill this.

1. Domain Account
2. Local Admin on the server.

You can install the SharePoint as well as SQL server under the same account, this is only for dev or test farm not recommend for the Production at all.

I dont see any problem with the workflow, could you please share the screen where you get invalid users.

Comment: It displayed "Specified RunAs account is invalid" when I use the domain account that I use for Sharepoint.

Comment: I am sorry, i am missing, could you pleae share the screen shot where you run as account...

Comment: Sorry about the confusing. I was talking about when configure workflow manager, at the point where it required a "RunAs" account, and it did not like my domain account. So I use a local account instead and I suspect that's why I got error when I open the workflow site.

Comment: you are talking about service account? check this technet..2nd image https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193514(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: I followed all the instructions but still failed. And also I have to log in as local account when I configure workflow manager too. If I use domain account but configure local account as service account, it still fails.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3026799   Seems like this is where I am stuck at.

Comment: can you get that permission on active directory from your admins?

Comment: Did the problem (can't open the site) was caused by using local account as service account? It would be difficult for me to get the permission because it's a school active directory.

Comment: try this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193462%28v=azure.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I did that one a while ago. Did not work for me!